# connection with server was terminated - c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, connection

Am working on VC++ application. It runs as a background application and connects to the server for every hour. It normally works really good but sometimes am receiving an error "The connection with server was terminated abnormally".

Does anyone have any idea to deal with this ?

Answer (score 3):

Could be a reason of network congestion or server load, you should change the code to retry a configurable no of time until connection succeeds.